# How to "build Turbolinks.framework" for ios?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks, turbolinks-ios

I haven't done any work building mobile apps with Rails, but I followed the very informative RailsConf demo from Sam Stephenson on Turbolinks 5 as a tool for building cross platform Apps with rails, [Turbolinks 5 Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWEts0rlezA) and it looks great.  The only part I can't replicate is how to get the "Turbolinks.framework" file that needs to be embedded in the iOS app shell.

The documentation at github's Turbolinks-ios page refers to a number of package managers for iOS (Carthage and CocoaPods) with which I am unfamiliar, or alternatively suggests "building Turbolinks manually and linking to my project."  I think he demos the linking part, but no idea how to "build Turbolinks manually".  Can someone give me a clue?

Comment: Interesting. I watched the video. Personally, I turn off Turbolinks in all my projects. I don't see anything in the video that is actually dependent on Turbolinks. But, I might just be missing the point altogether. That would not be unheard of.

Comment: I think turbolinks plus turbolinks-ios together make is what makes its possible to render the view on the server and make it show up within something that looks like an app on the ios device.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done straight development like that. But I have done something different using Rails.

All you need is creating React-Native app web view implemented and pass url to rails pages (make sure rails app supports mobile responsive css). Including there you can benefit turbolinks events. It will save your precious time, and also, faster development!

Comment: Thanks, but I like the idea of building the html on the server.  I think it will simplify things a lot to have one set of views that I can build on the server and send out to all kinds of different clients, including os and android.  Just need to figure out how to get that Turblinlinks.framework somehow!

Comment: use turbolinks in rails part and. for u just need a webview the page from react-native. The same process happens in yr option also!

Comment: I know the process happens, but I just don't to have to learn frontend another framework if I can avoid it.  I already use Angular and could do without the learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be very straightforward to install cocoapods and then use that to install Turbolinks-ios as mentioned on the git hub page.